# mysql INSERT INTO results in NULL values

Tags: mysql

So I am trying to insert the results of a query into the column 'unique_id' in my Listings_20220116 table, and all I get as a result are null values in the column. The query does not report any errors and seems to be working, but the desired values are not added to the column.

```
ALTER TABLE Listings_20220116 
ADD COLUMN unique_id VARCHAR(100);

INSERT INTO Listings_20220116 (unique_id)
SELECT 
  CONCAT(CAST(Date AS CHAR), Lookup)
FROM Listings_20220116;
```

If I create a new table using the below query then it works, but I want to add the values to the existing table:

```
CREATE TABLE xxx
SELECT *, CONCAT(CAST(Date AS CHAR), Lookup) AS 'Unique_ID'
FROM Listings_20220116 l ;
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an UPDATE not an INSERT

INSERT add always a new row.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Listings_20220116 (id int,`Date`DATE, Lookup varchar(5));
>
> INSERT INTO Listings_20220116 VALUES (1, NOW(),"a"),(2, NOW(),'b'),(3, NOW(),'C');
> ALTER TABLE Listings_20220116 
> ADD COLUMN unique_id VARCHAR(100);
>
> UPDATE Listings_20220116 
> SET unique_id = CONCAT(CAST(Date AS CHAR), Lookup)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Listings_20220116
> ```
>
> ```
> id | Date       | Lookup | unique_id  
> -: | :--------- | :----- | :----------
>  1 | 2022-01-26 | a      | 2022-01-26a
>  2 | 2022-01-26 | b      | 2022-01-26b
>  3 | 2022-01-26 | C      | 2022-01-26C
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1d7167d829bcdf1cf96d53ff4bf4422c)*